# How do I stop GCC from allocating a C array over another variable

Tags: c, gcc, memory, stack

I was recently playing around with libev and network programming and I noticed a weird behavior. The following code resulted in an "w->fd is not a socket" error.

```c
static void client_callback(struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w, int revents) {
    char buffer[TS_BUFFER_SIZE] = "\0";
    int len = recv(w->fd, buffer, TS_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    
    // ...
}
```

In fact, removing the `= "\0"` resulted in the code working. The problem was, that somehow, the address of `w->fd` and `buffer` overlapped, so that setting `buffer` to all zeroes overrode the contents of `w->fd`.

How could that happen and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: Do you have a version where you print out the address and size of of both buffer and `w->fd`?

Comment: The size of the buffer is 256 bytes and w->fd is a 32-bit int

Comment: The addresses are 0x7ffd99152838 (for fd) and 0x7ffd991527d0 (for buffer)

Comment: Most likely the error is in the caller passing in `w` (or whatever allocated that) - it really shouldn't be overlapped with the callee's local variables

Comment: Ah, I see my error, instead of aloocating it on the head, I had it on the stack and it went out of scope, so w was a hanging pointer. thx!